# XSLT output formatting: removing line breaks, and blank output lines from removed elements while keeping indent

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML:

```
<doc xmlns="http://www.foo.org">
  <div>
    <title>Mr. Title</title>
    <paragraph>This is one paragraph.
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph>Another paragraph.
    </paragraph>
    <list>
      <orderedlist>
        <item>
          <paragraph>An item paragraph.</paragraph>
        </item>
        <item>
          <paragraph>Another item paragraph</paragraph>
        </item>
      </orderedlist>
    </list>
  </div>    
</doc>
```

Here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:doc">
  <xsl:element name="newdoc" namespace="http://www/w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:div">
  <segment title="{foo:title}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </segment>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:title">
  <xsl:element name="h2">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:paragraph">
  <xsl:element name="p">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:list">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:orderedlist">
  <xsl:element name="ol">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:item">
  <xsl:element name="li">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo:item/foo:paragraph">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output:

```
<newdoc xmlns="http://www/w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <segment xmlns="" title="Mr. Title">
    <h2>Mr. Title</h2>
    <p>This is one paragraph.
    </p>
    <p>Another paragraph.
    </p>

      <ol>
        <li>
          An item paragraph.
        </li>

        <li>
          Another item paragraph
        </li>
      </ol>

  </segment>    
</newdoc>
```

I would like to change 3 things about this output:

1. remove the line break from the "p" elements (originally paragraph)
2. remove the line breaks from the "li" elements (produced when item/paragraph elements were removed)
3. remove the extra blank lines created when the list items were removed

-I have tried `<xsl:template match="foo:list/text()[normalize-space(.)='']" />` for #3, but this messes with the indentation

-I have also tried `<xsl:template match="foo:paragraph/text()[normalize-space(.)='']" />` for #1, but this has no effect on the line breaks

-And I have tried `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` but this eliminates all indentation

Thank you!!

Comment: You wrote _"I have tried `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` but this eliminates all indentation"_ That's true **only for input sources**. And by the way, it solves problems 2 and 3. For addressing 1 you need `<xsl:template match="text()"> <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/> </xsl:template>` as suggested in @Mads Hansen's answer.

Comment: Good question again, +1. See my answer for a short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 16):

Adding these templates to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

Produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newdoc xmlns="http://www/w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <segment xmlns="" xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com" title="Mr. Title">
        <h2>Mr. Title</h2>
        <p>This is one paragraph.</p>
        <p>Another paragraph.</p>
        <ol>
            <li>An item paragraph.</li>
            <li>Another item paragraph</li>
        </ol>
    </segment>
</newdoc>
```

The template with `match="*/text()[normalize-space()]"` will match `text()` nodes if the string returned from [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space) has some value. An empty string from an all whites-space `text()` would evaluate to `false()` and not be matched. The other template matches the opposite condition, and since it is an empty template, will eliminate the white-space only `text()` from the output.

Comment: That fixed #1 for me, thanks! However, I didn't get the same output as you... I still get the line breaks in "li" and blank lines before and after the "ol" elements. Seems to be wherever an element was removed remains unaffected. Is there maybe a better way to remove elements that doesn't leave space behind?

Comment: Hmm, when I ran it through Xselerator using AltovaXML, it generated that output that I posted that didn't have the whitespace lines, but I did get them running through Saxon.  I've added another template matching for whitespace-only `text()` nodes that produces the posted output and should address your other items.

Comment: _"using AltovaXML"_ means that whitespace only text nodes are stripped, the same as using `xsl:strip-space elements="*"`.

Comment: Adding the `<xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />` line eliminates indenting (throws everything into one line) just as `xsl:strip-space elements="*"` did.  BTW, I am using Firefox's XSLT.

Comment: Scratch that. Looks like Firefox's default processor was taking out the formatting. I installed another processor and all of the answers work great. Sorry for the trouble and thank you for the help!!

Comment: An interesting side effect of adding this is that (in my case at least) the process now runs much faster (with xsltproc): down from 20s to 0.1s (in my case, a hand-written filter turning 36k lines of HTML into LaTeX). I was sufficiently surprised that I double-checked the timings!

Comment: Can anyone maybe explain how these templates work or point me in the right direction? In particular I do not understand what the `[normalize-space()]` part of the match rule means.

Comment: @T-Dawg I'll add some context to the answer, but in short the `[]` is a predicate that functions sort of like a `WHERE` clause in SQL filtering all of the matched items and keeping only those that return `true()` for the expression inside. `normalize-space()` collapses all whitespace characters and eliminates leading/trailing whitespace. If any characters are left, they return `true()`, if empty (because was all whitespace) then would evaluate to `false()` and be filtered out.

Answer (score 8):

**At the very end of the stylesheet add these two templates**:

```
<xsl:template match=
"text()[not(string-length(normalize-space()))]"/>

<xsl:template match=
"text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;&#xD;', '  ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**You now get the wanted result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newdoc xmlns="http://www/w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <segment xmlns="" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org" title="Mr. Title">
      <h2>Mr. Title</h2>
      <p>This is one paragraph.         </p>
      <p>Another paragraph.         </p>
      <ol>
         <li>An item paragraph.</li>
         <li>Another item paragraph</li>
      </ol>
   </segment>
</newdoc>
```

Comment: This removes all indenting (throws everything into one line) as well.  Is this because I'm using the Firefox XSLT?

Comment: @Zori: I have run the transformation with 9 different processors -- none of them loses indentation. I don't have the FF XSLT processor. :(

Comment: Sure enough, the Firefox's default processor was taking out the formatting. I installed another processor and all of the answers work great. Sorry for the trouble and thank you for the help!!

Comment: @Zori: Glad that at the end you found the cause of the problem. You could consider now accepting one of the answers :)